# mandrill and nested merge vars

Tags: ruby, handlebars.js, mandrill

I am using handlebars for mandrill templates. And was wondering how to use nested merge vars? I am using ruby's mandrill-api gem.

```
global_merge_vars: [
  {name: 'receiver_name', content: receiver_name},
  {name: 'email_message.from_email', content: email_message.from_email},
  {name: 'email_message.from_phone', content: email_message.from_phone},
  {name: 'email_message.message_body', content: email_message.message_body},
],
```

In template:

```
<pre style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0">
    {{email_message.message_body}}
</pre>
```

But it doesn't work. However, for "receiver_name" it works.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: The {{email_message.message_body}} resolves to empty string.

Answer (score 2):

`{{email_message.xxx}}` resolves to empty string because Handlebars tries to access property `xxx` of `email_message`, and it doesn't exist, because it's not nested.

At the moment, it appears that you can't create nested vars inside `global_merge_vars` (see [Mandrill doc](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-)).

But I'm not sure if nested vars are needed here. So you should be able to simply replace your `.` by `_`, and it will work:

```
global_merge_vars: [
  {name: 'receiver_name', content: receiver_name},
  {name: 'email_message_from_email', content: email_message.from_email},
  {name: 'email_message_from_phone', content: email_message.from_phone},
  {name: 'email_message_message_body', content: email_message.message_body},
],
```

In your template:

```
<pre style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0">
  {{email_message_message_body}}
</pre>
```